# Drupal 7 creating rest service through services module

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Inspiring from http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-custom-web-services-for-drupal-7-0, I'm creating a rest api / webservice in D7. I installed required modules e.g. ctools, services, libraries, entity etc and created the content type "Housing Scheme" as mentioned in the valuebound.com.

Then as per valuebound, I have created a custom module named "housing_schemes_services". In this folder I created three files named:

> housing_schemes_services.info
> housing_schemes_services.module
> housing_schemes.services.inc

The .info file content is:

```
name = Housing Schemes Services
description = WebService APIs for Housing Schemes.
core = 7.x
package = Housing Schemes
project = housing_schemes
dependencies[] = services
dependencies[] = rest_server
```

The .module file content is below:

```
function housing_schemes_services_services_resources() {
  $resources = array();

  //Include the necessary inc files.
  module_load_include('inc', 'housing_schemes_services', 'housing_schemes.services');

  //Service Apis for contents.
  $resources += housing_schemes_services_resource();

  return $resources;
}

function housing_schemes_services_resource_retrieve($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  //Check if the node type is housing schemes.
  if ($node->type == 'housing_scheme') {
    //Get PROPERTY DESCRIPTION data from field collection.
    $property_description = $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    // here we are loading field collection
    $pd_item = field_collection_item_load($property_description);

    $return_obj = array(
      'scheme_name' => $node->title,
      'scheme_id' => $node->nid,
      'created_date' => $node->created,
      'about_scheme'=>$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
      'distance_from_the_city'=>$node->field_distance_from_the_city[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
      'nearest_major_city' => $node->field_nearest_major_city[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
      'distance_from_the_city' => $node->field_distance_from_the_city[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
      'locality_review' =>$node->field_locality_review[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],  
      //'property_description' => $pd_item_values,
    );
  }
  return $return_obj;
}
```

The .inc file content is:

```
function housing_schemes_services_resource() {
  $api = array(
    'housing_schemes' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'retrieve' => array(
          'help' => 'Retrieves housing schemes info.',
          'file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'housing_schemes_services',
            'name' => 'housing_schemes.services',
          ),
          'callback' => 'housing_schemes_services_resource_retrieve',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'nid',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'Function to perform',
              'source' => array(
                'path' => '0'
              ),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $api;
}
```

When I entered http://localhost/drurest/cf_api/housing_schemes/1.json , it works fine e.g. as below:

```
{"scheme_name":"House 1","scheme_id":"1","created_date":"1516180661","about_scheme":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.","distance_from_the_city":"10 km","nearest_major_city":"Dallas","locality_review":"Good"}
```

Now, I want to create CRUD functionality through this services module? How can I achieve this? Like, data can be added / updated/ deleted into Drupal, through webservices. Seeking your help.